# C#'s StringInfo and TextElementEnumerator can't recognize graphemes properly

Tags: c#, string, unicode, icu, grapheme

In C# `StringInfo` and `TextElementEnumerator` classes provide methods and properties for text elements.
And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2), we can find the definition of the **Text Element**.

> The .NET Framework defines a text element as a unit of text that is
>   displayed as a single character, that is, a **grapheme**. A text element
>   can be any of the following:

Yes, it says a text element is a grapheme in .NET. I also tested with some unicode characters myself, and it really seemed true until I tested one Korean letter '**가**'.

As we all know some Unicode characters consist of multiple code points. Also we may face code point sequences and that's the reason I'm using `StringInfo` and `TextElementEnumerator` instead of simple `String`.

`StringInfo` and `TextElementEnumerator` could tell if `Char`s were surrogate pairs correctly. And "\u0061\u0308", a Unicode character which consists of multiple code points, was recognized as one text element just as expected. But as for "\u1100\u1161", it failed to say that it was also one text element.

"\u1100" is a leading letter "ㄱ", and "\u1161" is a vowel letter "ㅏ". They can be individual characters and shown to the users just as I write here and you can see them now. But if they are used together, they are rendered as one character "가" instead of "ㄱㅏ".

There are two ways in order to represent a Korean character "가":

1. Using a single code point **U+AC00** from **Hangul Syllable**.
2. Using two code points **U+1100** and **U+1161** from **Jamo**.

Most of the time the former is used. The latter is rarely used, to be honest, I can't imagine when it's used at all..
Anyway, the first one is just one precomposed letter and the second is a sequence of **Lead** and **Vowel** which is treated as one character. When rendered they look the exactly same and both are actually canonically equivalent.
Also the following line returns true in C# :

```
"\u1100\u1161".Normalize() == "\uAC00"
```

I wonder why `Normalize()` here works just fine when C# doesn't think they are one complete text element..
I thought it had something to do with my .NET's version, but it turns out it's not the case. This thing happens even in Mono too.

I tested this with `ICU` as well, and it could treat "\u1100\u1161" as one grapheme **correctly**!
I initially thought `StringInfo` and `TextElementEnumerator` could eliminate need for **ICU4C** in some simple cases, so I'm very disappointed now..

Here's my question :

Am I doing something wrong here?

or

A Text Element in .NET isn't a user-perceived character unlike in ICU?

Comment: `Am I doing something wrong here?` yes, your TL;DR is a horrible question :)
guess the question actually is `Why is Normalize treating Jamo character as one`?

Comment: @X39 `Normalize()` works correctly. That's what it does.

Comment: @X39 What I'm asking here is why `StringInfo` doesn't work correctly unlike `Normalize()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue here is that per the Korean standard [KS X 1026](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2008/08225-n3422.pdf), the two jamos `ㄱ` and `ㅏ` are distinct from their combined form `가`. In fact, this exact example is used in the official standard (see section 6.2).

Long story short, Microsoft attempted to follow the standard but other operating systems and applications don't necessarily do so. Hence you can get "malformed" content from other software / platforms that appears to be parsed incorrectly on Windows / in .NET, even though it is parsed "correctly" on those platforms.

You will either need to ensure your data is correctly formed in the first place (unlikely, given that the *de-facto* standard is to completely ignore the *official* standard) or you will need to use ICU (or a similar library) to deal with these cases.

Comment: Oh, your explanation makes sense. Thanks!